# EventBus is not triggering event on ASP.NET Core using Abp

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

I am trying to use EventBus as described [here](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/EventBus-Domain-Events).

Here is my EventData class

```cs
    public class UpdateEntryEventData: EventData
    {
        public long? AttributeId { get; set; }
        public int? TenantId { get; set; }
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
    }
```

Interface

```cs
    public interface IEntryEventManager: IEventHandler<UpdateEntryEventData>, ITransientDependency
    {

    }
```

The interface implementation

```cs
    public class EntryEventManager : DasServiceBase, IEntryEventManager
    {
        public void HandleEvent(UpdateEntryEventData eventData)
        {
            // Some logic when an entry is updated ...
        }
    }
```

Here is when I call the method to trigger the event.

```cs
public class EntryManager : DasDomainServiceBase, IEntryManager
{
   public IEventBus EventBus { get; set; }
   
   public EntryManager()
   {
     EventBus = NullEventBus.Instance;
   }

   public async Task<MessageOutput<Guid>> UpdateAsync(UpdateEntryInput input)
   {
      input.Entry = await _customDataManager.GetEntryAsync(input.Entry, AbpSession?.TenantId);

      var result = await _entryStore.UpdateAsync(input).ConfigureAwait(false);
                        
      EventBus.Trigger(new UpdateEntryEventData
      {
         TenantId = AbpSession.GetTenantId(),
         Id = input.Id,
         AttributeId = input.AttributeId
       });

       return new MessageOutput<Guid>(result, null);
    }   
}
```

Based on the explation of the tutorial if our class implements: IEventHandler, ITransientDependency it will be registered. But for some reason that I can't figure out now the event is not being triggered.

Comment: Try first registering your class in the `ConfigureServices`.

Comment: Thanks @Dusan but I figured out what was happening. Now it is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some updates on my code and it is working now.

- DasServiceBase removed

```cs
    public class EntryEventManager : IEntryEventManager
    {
        public void HandleEvent(UpdateEntryEventData eventData)
        {
            // Some logic when an entry is updated ...
        }
    }
```

- DasDomainServiceBase replaced by DasServiceBase
- Property EventBus must be public

```cs
public class EntryManager : DasServiceBase, IEntryManager
{
   public IEventBus EventBus { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: changing EventBus to public fixed my issue.